# Cannot read property 'Decoder' of undefined in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

For my music bot, whenever I try and play a song, it gives me this error in the console.

I asked a couple of my friends and they said it was a discord.js issue.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
(node:106608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Decoder' of undefined
    at AudioPlayer.playOpusStream (C:\Users\Keaton\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js:73:38)
    at VoiceConnection.play (C:\Users\Keaton\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\util\PlayInterface.js:75:28)
    at play (C:\Users\Keaton\Documents\Musix\system\music.js:39:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:106608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:106608) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The code of BasePlayer.js can be found on the git repository [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/client/voice/player/BasePlayer.js).

I have reinstalled discord.js but I still get the error. What should I do?

Comment: Have you installed the NPM discord.js audio packages? If so, are they properly defined in your code?

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I have installed the NPM discord.js audio packages and properly defined it in my code.

Comment: Can you upload the `music.js` file to [Hastebin](https://hasteb.in)? Also check line 39, column 8, That's triggering the error